# paypal recurring payment - how to create recurring profile without expresscheckout?

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I need to create one agreement with user where user need to pay amount for example "75$" (it will dynamic) . User create recurring profile with one time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the amount of charge will be differ on each cycle? If that is the case, you might need to use Billing Agreement with Reference Transaction.

No specific amount on each charge, no expiry date and also you can charge your buyer in future without having them login to their PayPal account.

Read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/).